# Lift Req object

Tags: scala, rest, lift, partial-application

in liftbook, there's an example of creating of a Req instance by using apply :

```
case Req(List("api", "expense", eid), "", GetRequest) =>
 () => showExpense(eid)
```

but when I look into api documentation, there are two apply() methods, but I don't know which one and how is ran in this example.

Also, is there a way, how to include `/a/b` and `/a/b/c` requests with one `case` ?

Also, is there a way, how to enumerate all possible requests in one `case` : guess : `case Req(List("api", "expense", eid), "", {GetRequest,PostRequest})`?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by `case`, this isn't an example of *creating* a `Req`, but an example of [pattern matching](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch03.html#PatternMatching) one.

> Also, is there a way, how to enumerate all possible requests in one `case`

It should be

```
case Req(List("api", "expense", eid), "", _)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, when I wrote all possible requests, I meant just some. Is there a way, how to handle this?

Comment: `case Req(List("api", "expense", eid), "", GetRequest | PostRequest)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to have a two tier pattern matching.  On that would match the Req with any Request and extracts the request, and another that matches the specific request.